# SharePoint 2016 Persian Language pack

Tags: 2016, language-pack

I need to develop a **Persian language pack** for **SharePoint Server 2016**, because there is no built-in Persian language pack in SharePoint server 2016 image file.

In IRAN we must pay for this language pack, but now i want to develop and create a package for this purpose and publish free in internet for public uses.

For example *the cost of a Persian language pack in IRAN is Equals to Microsoft SharePoint 2016 license*.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It would be extremely hard to try to translate everything on the page without the language pack. What I think you mean is how do you get around purchasing the language pack. I guess you could feed all your pages through google translate api, but that isn't ideal or recommended.

Answer (score -1):

there is a language pack in [this](http://sp2010persian.codeplex.com)

this pack is without calender and version is older than 2016 but is a good start for improvement pack and share free and open source

If your start project I will help to develop this pack too